# nested for and properties using Ant

Tags: ant

i have list of 10 properties file say `1.properties , 2 .pro ....10.properties` 
and another file called total.properties which has all the file properties names .

now the problem is  print all file contents which are mentioned in total.properies files 
Using ant script.

```
Eg:
1.properties
name:rajesh
languesknown:en,sp
2.properties
name:kumar
languesknown:en,fr,wd

total.properties
numbers: 1,2

output:
name:rajesh
languesknown:en,sp
name:kumar
languesknown:en,fr,wd
```

USing ant script.

i tried by

but everytime its printing first record i.e 1.properties but its iterating twice depends on no of contents in total properties . so could any one help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

ANT is not a scripting language. Best way to do this is embed a scripting language. The following example uses [Groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/The+groovy+Ant+Task)

## Example

```
├── build.xml
└── src
    ├── 10.properties
    ├── 1.properties
    ├── 2.properties
    ├── 3.properties
    ├── 4.properties
    ├── 5.properties
    ├── 6.properties
    ├── 7.properties
    ├── 8.properties
    ├── 9.properties
    └── total.properties
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="print-properties">

   <target name="bootstrap">
      <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
      <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/groovy-all.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.1.7/groovy-all-2.1.7.jar"/>
   </target>

   <target name="print-properties">
      <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>
      <groovy>
         new File("src/total.properties").eachLine {
            def props = new File("src/${it}")

            println props.name
            println props.text
         }
      </groovy>
   </target>

</project>
```

Notes

- The "bootstrap" target installs the groovy task jar
- The script reads each line of the "total.properties" file and then prints the name and contents of each filename found.